# How do I load Content Dynamically into windows 8 apps

Tags: html, application-pool, pool, dynamic-content

I just learned that Windows 8 app, can be developed with HTML5

I wish to know how to load content dynamically for the app, like a news app that changes the content when it is refreshed.

I learnt that pool service is needed, please explain??
Please provide me a **brief explanation!!**

Also list the **prerequisites** for developing this kind of app.

@Brennan I accept all the Details of prerequisites , and about the brief explanation, I haven't seen any articles for dynamic content.

I would like to have some tutorials or samples for some news app, that keeps on updating content over the internet.

I tried this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868272.aspx but didn't help me out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before developing any Windows Store apps, you'll need to download Visual Studio which you can do [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-2013).

Once that's done, I'd recommend looking at the included templates as well as the Windows Store app samples (found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps)) in order to get a functional understanding of Store apps.

Hope that helps you figure out a good place to get started!

Comment: I don't have any so called templates or sample for new type apps

Comment: Do i Need a web host for news type app

Comment: [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx#creating_a_project_and_choosing_a_template) has a great, easy to understand set of steps for developing Windows Store apps. An additional introduction to templates can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738343.aspx).

Comment: i Accept all those about requirements, all i need to know is a brief tutorial or sample that shows how to create a news like app.